# Comparison Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to determine if the integral is convergent or divergent using the comparison theorem. 
  $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1+sin^{2}x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

From what I know about the comparison theorem, I need to get the integral in the form of $$\frac{1}{x^{p}} $$ $p > 1$ (converges) $p<= 1$ (diverges) just not sure how to go about turning the integral into a form I can work with.

Comment: Note that $sin^2(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$, so you can bound the numerator.

Comment: More pertinently, $\sin^2{x} \geq 0$.

Comment: i think this integral doesn't converge on the given interval

Comment: No it doesn't, but to see that you'd want a comparison test with $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for $x\ge 1$,

$$0 <\frac {1}{\sqrt {x}}\le \frac {1+\sin^2 (x)}{\sqrt {x}} $$

and
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac {dx}{\sqrt {x}}$$ diverges.
thus your integral is divergent.